# Being full admin under Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, administrator

With Windows 8, every time I want to copy/paste/modify/write a file under the Windows partition, I get a message saying :

"You must be administrtor to copy/paste/modify/write in this folder/file".

I haven't found any way to gain full privilege under my own Windows 8 Professionnal, which I've installed from scratch.
I'm the only user. I'm administrator. And I can't give myself all access to the "Program Files" folder, it says for every folder inside that "There was an error, you don't have access to the specifyed file".

How can I solve this problem ? There is absolutely no satisfying solution on Google.
There must be a way somehow musn't it ?

EDIT : Disabling UAC doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: you may want to see this as well http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/144776-unable-to-open-an-elevated-windows-explorer-window/

Comment: Why are you putting files in protected folders?  Any directory within your profile won't give you this error if it does then you have system integrity problems.  Elevated permissions in program files is actually normal

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 on my laptop and in the same dialog it displays a button with a shield and Continue on it. When pressed, it will copy fine. Do not disable UAC or Admin Approval. It exists for a reason.

Comment: I have installed a program in my Program Files folder, and I'm modifying it. This is my own program I want to configure. Besides, I do want to deactivate it, that's my question. I know the risks. Disabling UAC doesn't solve the problem. I wouldn't have asked otherwise. @Kniuckle-Dragger : Good try, but it's only for Explorer ? What about the Full Admin Authorisation Package ?

Comment: This is NOT duplicate since I don't talk about UAC. And deactivating it doesn't solve the problem.